# Automation Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, automation

I need help with  Automation Studio.

I need to do a automated system that uses "Data extract" to take a "Data extension" and send it to my ftp server, and after that the system will do a "Import file" for a "list" to do a welcome e-mail, and my doubt is how can i setup these itens to do what i want, or if is possible how can i creat a automatic welcome e-mail based in a Data extension?

Comment: Go to the docs and read up about Data Extracts and ftp operations and attempt to solve it. If you get stuck come back

Comment: I read the docs but i didn't understand how to setup inside the automation studio the Data Extract and the File Transfer to take the Data extension that i want and to move to my ftp server

Comment: If you are not able to see the "Data Extension" Data Extract type in your Data Extract Activity then you need to raise a support ticket, to enable that extract type. After that just follow the documenation

Comment: No it's not that, I've the "DE" Data Extract type avaible but i ddo not know how to setup it to extract a DE and upload it to the "List" i did not found a way to do it, so if someone could help me with this or give me another way to send a welcome email to each people who subscribe in a DE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build an automation, with a query activity, that builds your audience by querying your original DE. Then either create an email activity in the next step of the automation, or a journey in Journey Builder with Automation Studio Audience entry event

Comment: But it will also work like a welcome email? because i need that every time that some new email is isert by my site into the DE this new email receive that  welcome email automatically

Comment: If you want it to happen in real time, you would need to go with a Triggered Send or Journey - both triggered by an API call. There is no way of triggering a welcome email in real time just basing on a new entry in a Data Extension.